# Why would (CodeIgniter) get_instance() not work?

Tags: php, codeigniter, tdd

I am trying to get PHPUnit (for TDD) working with CodeIgniter.

A perfectly reasonable guide that I am following is here: http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/codeigniter_phpunit_and_netbeans

But the problem I am getting is this:

```
c:\projects\project1\tests>phpunit .
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_instance() in c:\....\PostTest.php on line 7
```

which almost sounds like my whole CodeIgniter framework is not being seen.

I've modified the bootstrap.php file to have an explicit path to the system and application folders, just to be sure that it's not something simple like that. But no luck.

What does get_instance depend on to run? It's part of the core CodeIgniter framework.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error.

The problem is in the file phpunit.xml
You need to place it on 
`c:\projects\project1\tests>`

and you need to create the file bootstrap.php as on your link : 
http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/codeigniter_phpunit_and_netbeans

that's how your tests connect to your codeigniter